# No virtual method getActiveNotifications()

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic3, angular5

**I started to get the following error after upgrading my application to the following features. (the code has not changed)**

I did not get any errors in the tests, but firebase gave the users the knowledge that they got this error

I did not debug with the firebase console before. Could you help me, please ?

```
**ionic info:**
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
    Node : v8.9.3
    npm  : 5.6.0
    OS   : Windows 10
```

[firebase console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3zzw.jpg):

> ```
>  Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getActiveNotifications()[Landroid/service/notification/StatusBarNotification;
> ```
>
> in class Landroid/app/NotificationManager; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.app.NotificationManager' appears in
>   /system/framework/framework.jar)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.Manager.getIdsByType
>   (Manager.java:227)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.Manager.getByType
>   (Manager.java:279)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.Manager.clearAll
>   (Manager.java:160)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.clearAll
>   (LocalNotification.java:350)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification.access$900
>   (LocalNotification.java:59)
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification$1.run
>   (LocalNotification.java:164)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)

```
**package.json (dependencies):**
"@angular/common": "5.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.1.1",
"@angular/core": "5.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
"@angular/http": "5.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
"@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/app-rate": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.1.0",
"@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/network": "^4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.5.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.5.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
"cordova-android": "7.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-app-event": "^1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-apprate": "^1.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.5",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
"cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^1.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
"cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.0.7",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.1",
"cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
"cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "^0.8.5",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-audio": "^3.2.0",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.1.4",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.5",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.18"

**package.json (cordova plugins):**
  "cordova-plugin-console": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": {},
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
  "cordova-plugin-file": {},
  "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
  "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
  "cordova-plugin-apprate": {},
  "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
  "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {},
  "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}
```

### edit-1

- deleted the node_modules file
- removed all local-notification package
- installed "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.1"
- set notification period 'munite'

After done these i tested on adroid. App crashed and closed.
I understand that the error is happening showing notification.

- I cleaned all the notifications and app worked.

I think this package is not compatible with cordova 7.0.0.
Already in package version is beta.
I think I'll wait for the compatible release to come out...

[i think this github issue is same as my problem](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1469)

Comment: - I deleted the node_modules file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this moment Ionic Native does not support 0.9.* version of this plugin, [which brings breaking changes](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#important-notice). Also, you have two different versions of this plugin:

```
"cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.1",
"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "^0.8.5",
```

remove beta version and try it again. Also also, please [take a look on this thread](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1373), **cordova-plugin-firebase** can cause problems in your case.

Comment: Yes, i realized i did. Please look at **edit 1**  header.

Comment: @YamanŞehzade Again, take a look on[ionic native docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) and plugin docs. For this moment ionic supported version for this plugin is 0.8.5.Try to remove 0.9 and use 0.8.5 only